# How to check multiple values in a column MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I have a column with values i.e.

```
number   id
1        111
1        111
3        222
4        222
5        333
```

I'm checking if the I.D has more than one instance and if the number is the same as the second or more instance. So here, it would return 1 because there is 2x 1's with id 111, but 222 doesn't return because 3 and 4 are not the same.

How would I do such a query?

I was told that I could do two queries or more and on the second or more query I would ignore the first instance.

Comment: it's just the query i need to do, I need to return an instance where the number occurs more than once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, number
from the_table
group by id, number
having count(*)>1
```

you should have index defined on both `id, and number` column

ps: the order can be number, id ... depends on your composite index key

Comment: can you please explain in detail what you mean about the index?

Comment: the index is like a shortcut key to get the matched rows. to create index: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html and further reading http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

you should try using `group by` clause and see whether the output is what you expect:

`select number,id from table_name group by number;`

Answer (score 0):

[GROUP BY DOCS](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-group-by-clause.htm)

```
Select number,id from table_name group by number;
```

Comment: Why does this not return the other values I don't understand. Don't you have to specify COUNT in this?